# converting the object of user defined in String type

Tags: java, string

I have the below pojo named eurrexcashMessageObject with corresponding setters and getters

```
public class eurrexcashMessageObject implements Cloneable{  

    private String  PaymentDate;
    private String CCPTradeId;
    private String Currency;
    private String Contract_Id;
    private String PaymentAmount;

    //include seeters & getters also
    }
```

now there is a method in which i am retrieving the list

```
List<eurrexcashMessageObject> listcashmessage1 = eurexcashParsing.getcashmessageojects();
```

so as you can see that list which is retrieved is of eurrexcashMessageObject type now i am iterating over the list  as shown below..

```
for(int i = 0; i < listcashmessage1.size(); i++)
            {

                String PaymentDate = String.valueOf(listcashmessage1.get(0));
                String CCPTradeId  = String.valueOf(listcashmessage1.get(1));                                         
                String Currency = String.valueOf(listcashmessage1.get(2));
                String Contract_Id =  String.valueOf(listcashmessage1.get(3));
                String PaymentAmount = String.valueOf(listcashmessage1.get(4));
```

now i can see that in variable PaymentDate the string is not store and similar is the case for CCPTradeId,Currency,Contract_Id,PaymentAmount
can you please advise how can i convert the list contents into string within for loop

Comment: Please put more effort into formatting your code - and ideally, using conventional Java capitalization. The more readable the code in your question is, the more likely you are to get an answer.

Answer (score 2):

`listcashmessage1.get(0)` will return the object stored in the list at index 0. Call `listcashmessage1.get(i).yourGetter()` to get the actual value.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a for-each loop:

```
for (eurrexcashMessageObject emo : listcashmessage1) {
  String paymentDate = emo.getPaymentDate();
  //etc.
}
```